# What is the cleanest way to get rid of distractions in the a corner of my image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, image-editing

Take a look at my original:
[image: Original]

My goal here is to get rid of the curb at the bottom right corner.

I tried doing a doing a transform -> warp but the results aren't great. Even though the image itself is not very clear, the transformed area looks very distorted.

[image: Original]

What else can I do to get rid of the curb at the bottom right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeat a bokeh light pattern the most naturally in Photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/131436/repeat-a-bokeh-light-pattern-the-most-naturally-in-photoshop)

Comment: @Wolff can you answer your question as an answer so I can vote up and comment

Comment: I would love to, but I voted to close the question as a duplicate because I believe it's already answered in that other question. My answer here would be exactly the same as I answered on the other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the Content Aware fill in Photoshop.

Make a selection around the offending stonework using the Polygonal Lasso, then do *Edit > Fill*, and choose *Content Aware* as the fill type

Example

[image]

Comment: +1 I always forget about CA fill... danger of starting with Photoshop before it existed I guess. This is nice! I'd probably use this combined with a bit of my technique in the end.

Comment: If you choose *Edit > Content-Aware Fill* you get a dialogue with more options where you can specify which area to clone from. The filled area might look more natural if you included some of the left side as well.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty.. could be refined...

1 Copy left side area and flip it and move into position on the right.
[image]

2 Add a **Layer Mask** and, using the **Gradient Tool** on the mask, soften the edges around the area 
[image]

3 New layer. Use a **Brush** to paint on a general area  of the bright blue. Afterwards use `Filter > Blur > Gaussian Blur` to soften the edges
[image]

4 Set this brush layer mode to `Color Dodge`
[image]

5 Lower opacity of Color Dodge layer until you are happy
[image]

The edge closest to the path still needs a little attention in the above image, but this should provide a general methodology.

Comment: :clap: :clap: :clap: